# Why pom.xml ask a version for dependency?

Tags: java, maven, version, pom.xml, artifact

In pom.xml for hibernate:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

there is not version. But when I add to my application pom in Eclipse I receive error 
that version must be. Why this difference?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The 2.0 is the version of the JPA supported not the version of the artifact

try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Arnon

Answer (score 2):

Maven needs to know what version to download/check.

Add a `version` element as a child of `dependency`.

Comment: And why distributed hibernate pom doesn't contain?

Comment: @user710818 From a guess at the `artifactId`, I'd go with `2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

The extract you saw in the dependencies of hibernate actually has a version which is defined in a parent pom, in its dependencyMgmt section. This allows to only define in one place the version to use and all children of that parent pom only need to indicate which dependency they want and they automatically get the version specified in the parent.

Add a `<version>` in your case, or also use a dependencyMgmt section in your pom.xml to indicate the version of hibernate-jpa-2.0-api you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of resolving these issue:

-insert yourself the version such that Maven knows what dependency you need (it either searches in the local repository for it or downloads from a maven repository or you can give it a link from where to download it)

-add a parent that uses the artifact that you are calling and then you don't need the version (it takes the parent version)